# Why does systemd reap child process when running script with Fabric but not ssh?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, systemd, fabric

I am running a Python script over SSH on an Ubuntu 18.04.2 server.

When I use `ssh` to login to the server and run the script, and then terminate the ssh session, the Python script also terminates as expected (I'm not using nohup, &, etc.) However, when I run the same script using Fabric, and then terminate the local Fabric process, the python process on the server gets reaped by systemd. This is what the systemd status looks like:

```
● session-219.scope - Session 219 of user root
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/session-219.scope; transient)
Transient: yes
   Active: active (abandoned) since Fri 2019-12-27 00:56:07 PST; 2min 55s ago
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-0.slice/session-219.scope
           └─6872 /root/peacock/bin/python3 -m src.main

Dec 27 00:56:07 master systemd[1]: Started Session 219 of user root.
Dec 27 00:57:52 master sshd[6783]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
```

Is there a way to prevent systemd from reaping the child process, similar to the behavior of ssh? And why does it only get reaped when using Fabric but not ssh directly?

More details:

The Python script is a simple flask app. The gist of it is:

```
flask_app = Flask('app')

@flask.route('/')
def index():
  # ....

if __name__ == '__main__':
  flask_app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The Fabric script is roughly as follows:

```
server_conn = fabric.Connection('1.2.3.4')
with server_conn.cd('/root/peacock'):
  server_conn.run('/root/peacock/bin/python3 -m src.main')
```

Comment: What is `src.main`? Can you provide the code you are using to connect with Fabric and how you start the process?

Comment: @urban updated question with more details about script and fabric code.

Comment: I think that fabric (using paramiko internally if I remember) will open a session, run your command and terminate the session (this should happen when you exit the context manager). When the session is ripped down your process dies too, which is the same behaviour with ssh. I would suggest that you create a systemd unit (your own service) - it is 10 lines of config: https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/start-service-at-boot/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run a process as a daemon on the remote box, I would suggest that you make it a systemd unit. This way you can control it with standard commands and access its logs like any other service on the system.

Your config could look like (`/etc/systemd/system/peacock.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=Peacock systemd service.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/peacock/bin/python3 -m src.main

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Remember to `sudo chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/peacock.service`. Then your fabric script would look like:

```
server_conn = fabric.Connection('1.2.3.4')
with server_conn.cd('/root/peacock'):
  server_conn.run('systemctl start peacock.service')
```

Later you can check status on this service. You will also be able to access logs with `journalctl -u peacock`

Comment: Thanks a lot - making it a systemd unit is definitely the better way. However, I am trying to understand exactly what the difference is between Fabric/paramiko and plain SSH is that causes the former to get reaped by systemd but not the latter :)

Comment: @SSharan you said that when you close SSH the python script also terminates right? I think same thing happens when fabric script terminates since a `close()` should be invoked somewhere on exit.. Not 100% sure this is what you meant in the question